# I am trying to get a text box that assigns input data to a var and then runs the function to convert it to a YouTube embed url and displays that

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, bootstrap-modal

Im setting up a website that will display a youtube video with modal-bootstrap but my modal needs embed youtube and i have a separate page that has a function that will convert it and display it but i have to put the watch link in the code and want that to pull from the text box on the page and not have to change the code every time.

I have tried multiple different functions to communicate with each other and also tried to change my modal to pull from watch url but youtube denies the request. I have been everywhere from stackoverflow, w3, jsfiddle, codepen, and googled the crap out of it but no luck.

Im working with this fiddle as a base before i put it on the page:

http://jsfiddle.net/hangman5950/51gz6syu

I need the variable "myID" to to pull from what's in the text box then run that in the function and i feel like it's super simple but I haven't messed with any of this in years so i don't know anything. jajajaja

my text box and display of video and embed id:

```
<input type="text" id="wat" value="">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Convert</button>

<p id="emb"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById("wat").value;
  document.getElementById("emb").innerHTML = x;
}
 </script>
```

YouTube ID: 
     
      
Embed code:

---

my css:

```
 #myId {
    color: orange;
 }
```

---

my js:

```
function getId(url) {
    var regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=) 
([^#\&\?]*).*/;
     var match = url.match(regExp);

    if (match && match[2].length == 11) {
         return match[2];
     } else {
        return 'error';
    }
 }

 var myId = getId('wat');

 $('#myId').html(myId);

$('#myCode').html('<iframe width="560" height="315" 
src="//www.youtube.com/embed/' + myId + '" frameborder="0" 
  allowfullscreen></iframe>');
```

I am expecting the box to be assigned to a "emb" and then display the video and the results but instead i get error after error

Answer (score 0):

I made this work, hope this is what you need:

```
function getId(){
    var id = document.getElementById("wat").value;
    var regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
    var match = id.match(regExp);
        if (match && match[2].length == 11) {
           var myId = match[2];
            $('#emb').html('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + myId + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
         }else{
           return 'Error';
        }
}
```

And the HTML

```
<input type="text" id="wat" value="">

<button id="convert" onclick="getId()">Convert</button>

<p id="emb"></p>
```